# Allocating and initializing UIImageViews in an array of NSObjects

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to allocate and initialize UIImageViews that are part of an NSObject (Circle), and I have an array of these Circles. However, XCode doesn't like my allocating and initializing of the UIImageViews.

Here is the code:

```
//allocate and set circleArray
circleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    [circleArray addObject:[Circle alloc]];
    [[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] setTouched:0];
    [[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] imageView] = [[UIImageView alloc] init]; //Problem Here: "Expression is not assignable"
}

//some code setting up the columns and beats shown below

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    [[[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] imageView] setFrame:CGRectMake([[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] column]*80-75, [[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] beat]*80+5, 70, 70)];

    [self.view addSubview:[[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] imageView]];

    if ([[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] beatMod] == 0) {
        [[[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] imageView] setImage:redCircle];
    }
    else if ([[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] beatMod] == 0.5) {
        [[[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] imageView] setImage:blueCircle];
    }
    else if ([[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] beatMod] == 0.25 || [[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] beatMod] == 0.75) {
        [[[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] imageView] setImage:yellowCircle];
    }
    else {
        [[[circleArray objectAtIndex:i] imageView] setImage:greenCircle];
    }
}
```

If I take out the line with the error, then nothing shows up on the screen.
Am I supposed to allocate and initialize the UIImageViews for them to show up, or is that already done for me when I allocate and initialize the NSObject?
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't you need to `init` the `Circle` object in the first line of your for loop?
2. The syntax is a bit weird to me. The line that's causing you problem, its LHS is **returning** an object. You shouldn't **set** it to something. You should probably use cast like

   `((Circle *)[circleArray objectAtIndex:i]).imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];`
3. You may want to set up your `Circle` before adding it to the array. So just

   `Circle *c = [[Circle alloc] init];`

   `c.imageView = blablabla;`

   `[array addObject:c];`

or something like that.

(hmm.. not sure why block code doesn't work..)

Comment: Thanks! #2 worked (helps with some other problems as well, as I am pretty new to programming on XCode), and I don't know why I forgot #1. I prefer to take the short way instead of doing what you did on #3, and it seems to work, but it might be a bad programming habit.